# SELinux Permissive enabled; httpd error reporting

Tags: centos, centos6, selinux

I kept getting the following notice in apache /var/log/messages and many others same messages :

```
kernel: type=1400 audit(1422862414.790:3222): avc: denied { getattr } for pid=2484 comm="deliver" path="/var/panel/sieve/globalfilter.sieve" dev=dm-0 ino=659172 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_deliver_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=lnk_file
Kernel : type=1400 audit(1422862549.898:3244): avc: denied { getattr } for pid=2320 comm="httpd" path="/var/panel/hostdata/admin/public_html/Mywebsite_com$$ai_com/admin/ajax.php" dev=dm-0 ino=5625763 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
kernel: type=1400 audit(1422862414.813:3229): avc:  denied  { lock } for  pid=2484 comm="deliver" path="/var/panel/vmail/website.com/fail2ban/dovecot.index" index" dev=dm-0 ino=787081 scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_deliver_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
kernel: type=1400 audit(1422863078.135:3252): avc: denied { write } for pid=2740 comm="pop3" name="cur" dev=dm-0 ino=3794960scontext=system_u:system_r:dovecot_t:$cot_t:s0tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=dir
```

I lately installed SELinux permissive mode  , Help would be appreciates ..

THX

Comment: how do you tryied to fix it?

Comment: "chcon -t public_content_t '/var/panel/hostdata/admin/public_html/Mywebsite_com$$ai_com/admin/ajax.php'" but didn't help

Comment: Are you using some kind of web control panel?

Comment: Yes I am using Zpanel "var/panel/hostdata/admin/public_html/Mywebsite_com$$ai_com"

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to translate this message into more human readable text, try to use

```
audit2allow -w -a
```

Then - you can use

```
audit2allow -a -M mymodule
```

to automate create of selinux module which allow this type of activity, and then

```
semodule -i mymodule.pp
```

to install it into selinux.

Comment: 'audit2allow -w -a' Returned <no matches>
cd /var/log
tail messages | audit2allow

#============= ftpd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using one of the these booleans:
#     allow_ftpd_full_access, ftpd_connect_db
allow ftpd_t mysqld_db_t:dir search;

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using one of the these booleans:
#     allow_ftpd_full_access, ftpd_connect_db
allow ftpd_t mysqld_var_run_t:sock_file write;

#============= httpd_t ==============

Comment: logs to audit are usually in /var/log/audit/audit.log

Comment: I try to create module but I have the following problem :
'# audit2allow -a -M dovecot_t
<no matches>
compilation failed:
dovecot_t.te:6:ERROR 'syntax error' at token '' on line 6:


/usr/bin/checkmodule:  error(s) encountered while parsing configuration
/usr/bin/checkmodule:  loading policy configuration from dovecot_t.te
'

Comment: show /var/log/audit/audit.log - there should be info needed to create selinux module.

Comment: the /var/log/audit/audit.log in empty

Comment: I check the auditd service and was off ..

Comment: Now seems all done form that point , if I check again with ..... I have "  Unknown - would be allowed by active policy
                Possible mismatch between this policy and the one under which the audit message was generated.
 Possible mismatch between current in-memory boolean settings vs. permanent ones." for sure is related to permission  but not clear ....any Advice please